# clicking an element to remove other element class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a website I want to make a rule that, if `"all"` the div is clicked, the `"display: none"` `<div>` will appear by removing its `'none'` class. My code is not working and I don't understand why.

I've tried everything that I know, searching the web for an answer to this problem and I can't find anything that could help me with this particular situation.

```js
var check1;
var check2;

$("#btn-1").click(function() {
  check1 = 1;
});

$("#btn-2").click(function() {
  check2 = 1;
});

if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1) {
  $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
}
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 150px;
}

#btn-1 {
  bottom: 0;
}

#btn-2 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 250px;
}

#btn-3 {
  top: 0;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="btn-1">

</div>

<div id="btn-2">

</div>

<div id="btn-3" class="none">

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1) { $("#btn-3").removeClass("none"); }` in the function and call it inside the click event of the button click?

Comment: @Krusader I didn't call it from the inside click event as I thought javascript would just run on loop and check for any variable change. I know my mistake now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see what your code is really doing:

```
var check1;
var check2;

$("#btn-1").click(function() { // <-- this function is run after a click
  check1 = 1;
});

$("#btn-2").click(function() { // <-- this function is run after a click
  check2 = 1;
});

// <-- there are no clicks yet, so none of the above functions are run yet
// both click1 and click2 are undefined.

if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1) {
  // This does not run, because both click1 and click2 are undefined at this point
  $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
}
```

To fix this, you have to make sure the checks are done **after** the clicks happen. So:

```
var check1;
var check2;

$("#btn-1").click(function() {
  check1 = 1;
  checkClicks();
});

$("#btn-2").click(function() {
  check2 = 1;
  checkClicks();
});

function checkClicks() {
  if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1) {
    $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if all are clicked when you click a button...

```
var check1, check2;

$("#btn-1").click(function() {
    check1 = 1;
    if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1)
        $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
});

$("#btn-2").click(function() {
    check2 = 1;
    if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1)
        $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add your if in event :

```
var check1;
var check2;

$("#btn-1").click(function() {
  check1 = 1;
  if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1) {
    $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
  }
});

$("#btn-2").click(function() {
  check2 = 1;
  if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1) {
     $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

create a function something like

```js
var check1;
var check2;

$("#btn-1").click(function() {
  check1 = 1;
  checkHide()
});

$("#btn-2").click(function() {
  check2 = 1;
  checkHide()
});

function checkHide(){
if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1) {
  $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
}
}
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 150px;
}

#btn-1 {
  bottom: 0;
}

#btn-2 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 250px;
}

#btn-3 {
  top: 0;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="btn-1">

</div>

<div id="btn-2">

</div>

<div id="btn-3" class="none">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The if condition that you placed outside the click even needs to be inserted inside those 2 click events.

Please have a look to the snippit for the solution.

Best Regards and Happy Coding ;)

```js
var check1;
var check2;

$("#btn-1").click(function() {
  check1 = 1;
  if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1) {
  $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
}
});

$("#btn-2").click(function() {
  check2 = 1;
  if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1) {
  $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
}
});
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 150px;
}

#btn-1 {
  bottom: 0;
}

#btn-2 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 250px;
}

#btn-3 {
  top: 0;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="btn-1">

</div>

<div id="btn-2">

</div>

<div id="btn-3" class="none">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional statement within the code block of the `click` event, otherwise your `if` statement will not fire when the conditions are met `true`

```js
var check1;
var check2;

$("#btn-1").click(function() {
  check1 = 1;
  console.log(check1);

  if (check1 && check2) {
    $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
  }
});

$("#btn-2").click(function() {
  check2 = 1;
  console.log(check2);

  if (check1 && check2) {
    $("#btn-3").removeClass("none");
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 150px;
}

#btn-1 {
  bottom: 0;
}

#btn-2 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 250px;
}

#btn-3 {
  top: 0;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="btn-1">

</div>

<div id="btn-2">

</div>

<div id="btn-3" class="none">

</div>
```